# show $\max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| \le \frac 1 2 \, \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)|$ for cantor function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am reading some stuff about the Cantor set and found a construction on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Iterative_construction):

$$f_{n+1}(x)=\begin{cases}
0.5\cdot f_n(3x)&\textrm{if }0\leq x<\frac13\\
0.5&\textrm{if }\frac13\leq x\leq \frac23\\
0.5+0.5\cdot f_n(3x-2)&\textrm{if }\frac23< x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Then it holds $$\max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| \le \frac 1 2 \, \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)|.$$

Why? I've tried to proove it but I can't get any good result. It is clear that you have to do it cases-by-cases, but how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use induction, suppose its valid for $k = 1, 2, \dots , n$, that is
$$  \, \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)| \le \frac 1 2  \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n-1}(x) - f_{n-2}(x)|$$

Now if $x \in [0,\frac 1 3]$

$$\max_{x \in [0, \frac 1 3 ]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_{n}(x)| = \frac 1 2 \max_{x \in [0, \frac 1 3]} |f_{n}(3x) - f_{n-1}(3x)| $$ $$ \leq \frac 1 4  \max_{x \in [0, \frac 1 3]} |f_{n-1}(3x) - f_{n-2}(3x)| = \frac 1 2  \max_{x \in [0, \frac 1 3]} |f_{n}(x) - f_{n-1}(x)| $$